# How to resize child div to the clicked point or area on clicking in the parent div using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Child div width should be  increase till the area it has been clicked on the parent div like if I click at the width area 720px ,width of the child div gets width 720px

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. here is an example that might help.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".child").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: $(this).parent().width()
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 720px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.child {
  width: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">x</div>
</div>
```